# Issue converting to seconds

Tags: java, logic

Can anyone assist me as to why my seconds are not printing out correctly? The hours and minutes are both correct, but it is not printing out anything for the **secs** variable. The items in my arraylist are in **System.currentTimeMillis()**, which is why I have to convert them.

```
//divides 'logoutTimeTotal' by 'loginTimeTotal' to get 'totalTimeLoggedIn'
long totalTimeLoggedIn = (((totalTimeArray.get(1) - totalTimeArray.get(0)) / 1000) / 60);

//creates 2 variables that convert time logged in to hours and minutes
long hr = totalTimeLoggedIn / 60;
long min = totalTimeLoggedIn - (hr * 60);
long secs = totalTimeLoggedIn;

//creates String variable with hours and minutes logged in
String timeLoggedStr = hr + " Hours " + min + " Minutes " + secs + " Seconds";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is when you getting the `totalTimeLoggedIn`, you do:

```
long totalTimeLoggedIn = (((totalTimeArray.get(1) - totalTimeArray.get(0)) / 1000) / 60);
```

If you want to get the total time in second that generating using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, then you have to divide just on `1000`,since the `1 second is 1000 milliseconds`, so you need to do:

```
long totalTimeLoggedIn = (((totalTimeArray.get(1) - totalTimeArray.get(0)) / 1000));
```

Comment: could I ask for one more piece of advice?

Comment: @javaGeek Yea sure, go a head please?

Comment: @javaGeek Then Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by rounding.

Instead of `long`, using `float` is better.